# converting a string to date in the exact manner

Tags: c#, string, date

I have a string "11 Jan 2011" which I want to convert to the datatype date (i.e 11 Jan 2011).

I have tried all resources about `datetime.parse`, `datetime.parse` exact but all these things gives me the same output 2011/01/11 12:00:00 AM. I really don't understand this behaviour. I tried the following:

1.`DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("11 Jan 2011")`;

2.`DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("11 Jan 2011" , @"dd MMM yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`;

Comment: What's the problem?  It's called Date **Time** class for a reason.

Comment: "2011/01/11" **is** the 11th Jan 2011. By "12:00:00 AM" do you mean 12:00:00?

Comment: Gives you the same output where? Once it is DateTime you can return it in any string format you want. Looks like you are doing it correctly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Comment: what time would you like the `DateTime` to have? Have you made your own `Date` type?

Answer (score 6):

parsing and displaying are not the same thing

you parse the original string to a DateTime object but display results using [Date/Time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Both your calls are correct.

A `DateTime` structure preserves no information about *formatting*; it just represents the raw date and time.

What you need to do is ensure that when you *display* your date, you do so in the correct format - e.g. by calling `string displayString = date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");`